# JQuery.ajax error. can't figure out the issue

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get this search box on the autocomplete html page to display results using the JSON provided from the birdws.java web service. Everytime I enter text into my text box it gives me an error. The JSON text that the birdws provides validates on JSONLint.com, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and I've been staring at this for hours. I don't know what to do.

This is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Auto Complete</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            // $ <-- means you are accessing jQuery 
            $('document').ready(function(){
                $('#txtBirdComName').keyup(function(){
                    var url;
                    var typedText = $('#txtSearch').val();
                    url = "rest/birdws?birdComName=" + typedText;
                    getDataFromWebService(url);
                });
            });


            function getDataFromWebService(targetUrl){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: targetUrl,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
                        alert("win!");
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                        alert("Something went wrong!" + "\n" +
                                "Status: " + status + "\n"); // <---- keeps erroring
                        console.log(jqXHR.toString());
                    }       
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainContent">
            <input type="text" name="txtBirdComName" id="txtBirdComName" value="" /> 
            <br><br>
            <table id="tblBirds" border="1">

            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the web service:

```
package edu.pitt.rest;

import edu.pitt.core.Bird;
import edu.pitt.utilities.DbUtilities;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 *
 * @author CS_User
 */
@WebServlet(name = "birdws", urlPatterns = {"/rest/birdws"})
public class birdws extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Bird bird = null;

            String birdComName = "";

            if(request.getParameter("birdComName") != null){
                birdComName = request.getParameter("birdComName");
            }

            DbUtilities db = new DbUtilities();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM birds ";
            if(!birdComName.equals("")){
                sql += "WHERE birdComName LIKE '" + birdComName + "%' ";
                sql += "LIMIT 20";
            }


            JSONArray fullBirdList = new JSONArray();
            ResultSet rs;
                try {
                    rs = db.getResultSet(sql);
                    // use this to get the length of rs
                    int rowcount = 0;
                    if (rs.last()) {
                    rowcount = rs.getRow();
                    rs.beforeFirst(); // use this to place rs back to the front
                    }
                    //out.printf("[");
                    while(rs.next()){
                        bird = new Bird(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("birdID")));
                        JSONObject birdJSON = bird.toJSON();

                        if(rs.getRow() != rowcount){
                            out.printf(birdJSON.toString() + ",");
                        }else{
                            out.printf(birdJSON.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    //out.printf("]");

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(birdws.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
             db.closeDbConnection();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below code to see what the error is, it generally explains what is the thrown error

```
error: function(jqXHR, status, thrownError) {
                    alert("Something went wrong!" + "\n" +
                            "Status: " + status + "\n"); // <---- keeps erroring
                    alert(thrownError);
                    console.log(thrownError);
                }
```

Comment: alert(thrownError); // doesn't display

Comment: try removing the above alert and see if it works  alert("Something went wrong!" + "\n" +
                            "Status: " + status + "\n"); // <---- keeps erroring not required

Comment: console.log(thrownError); 
says: Uncaught ReferenceError: thrownError is not defined

Comment: I removed the alert preceding it and it wouldn't display

Comment: if you can alert the error , do u still need to log it to the console. if not try removing it and place it in somehtml as

error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
  alert(thrownError); 
$("#dialogForm").html('<p>' + thrownError + '</p>');
  },

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/CS_User/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SRP63_greenroof2/web/rest/birdws?birdComName=ame. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: looks like your webservice is not available over http, if you see the above error you can see something as file:///C:/Users, which a ajax request wont understand. See if your webservice is been exposed properly and then try to access it. Before accessing that try using some webservice client to access it and get the response.